# Mapping firebase data in ionic list

Tags: angularjs, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am storing my data in firebase with `update()` like so

```
    var newKey = firebase.database().ref().push().key;

    var updates = {};
    updates['metadata/' + newKey] = {
        name: $scope.formData.name,
        price: $scope.formData.price
    };

    updates['realdata/' + newKey] = {
        name: $scope.formData.name,
        price: $scope.formData.price,
        date: $scope.formData.date
    };

    return firebase.database().ref().update(updates)
    .then(function(ref){
        console.log("added in fb");
    }, function(error){
        console.log("error " + error)
    });
```

Now on an other page I am pulling the data out of firebase, but I can't seem to map it to my list in my view.

I tried multiple ways to pull the data out and in both ways I can see the data when logging it to the console.

```
    var dbRef = firebase.database().ref('/metadata');
    //Method 1
    $scope.list = $firebaseArray(dbRef);
   /*
     Result here in the console is an array with objects
     but when setting this in my list, I get the same amount of items pulled out but they are empty
   */ 

    //Method 2 - I prefer this way as per docs it's a best practice
     var loadmetadata = function(data){
         console.log(data.val().name); // I get the actual name
         $scope.list = data.val().name
     };

     dbRef.on('child_added', loadmetadata);
     dbRef.on('child_changed', loadmetadata);
```

My view is just a simple

```
<ion-item ng-repeat="listitem in list">
{{ listItem.name }}
</ion-item>
```

What am I missing? I prefer the second method, if someone can help me achieve this?

The thing is I've found someone with the same problem here on SO, and he was able to solve it with the methods I have above. Here is the link to the question/answer [Firebase 3 get list which contain generated keys to ionic list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39317711/firebase-3-get-list-which-contain-generated-keys-to-ionic-list)

The only difference I am seeing is that he's sorting the results, but I don't need that currently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just figured it out! Instead of using $firebaseArray, I need to use the $firebseObject method.

```
$scope.metadataObj = $firebaseObject(dbRef);
```

and in my view I can do the following:

```
<ion-item  ng-repeat="(key, value) in metadataObj">{{value.name}}</ion-item>
```

This method contains all the child methodes too. So no need to listen for them separetely.